# Uploaded file's size mismatch

Tags: c#, web, soap, encoding

I'm a junior software developer trying to learn more about web development and for now I'm wondering about this thing.

I'm sending a file trough multiple SOAP web requests, in chunks of 100.000 bytes, the first chunk's request has "start" operation, the other ones have "next" and the last chunk is sent with an "end" operation in the request's envelope. In the image below you can see how the envelope look.

[image]

I cannot check the file's content myself but I can only see the uploaded file's SIZE.
The uploaded file's size is always a quarter of the actual file size that I've sent.
For example if I have a 300.000 bytes file to send, the uploaded file's size will be approximately of size 75.000 . A proper example can be seen below.

I'm not sure if I actually understand how this works or even if the file is uploaded correctly.
If someone could explain this to me I would greatly appreciate it. :D

Thank you a lot for your time!

PS: I tweaked with the chunkLength parameter ( from the envelope ) or the actual buffer size ( trying 1000 bytes per request or even 100.000 ), the result is the same. :)

PS2: The data is a random string that I first gzip compress it then send it trough the request mentioned before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The upload is using Compression. Probably GZIP.

Comment: "The data is a random string that I first gzip compress " - are you decompressing it on the server?

Comment: Nope, the file on the server is an archive. Also, I'm compressing the string before uploading.